# Why does this dialogue appear in the transcript but not the episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

The [Chakoteya transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/440.htm) of DS9: The Maquis, Part I contains a long chunk of dialogue between Sisko and the Admiral.

> S2, E20 ("The Maquis", part 1, third last scene [Ops]).
>
> **SISKO**: I'm hoping I don't have to remind the admiral how many people pass through here during a week's time. It's not possible to keep tabs on every single person while they're on the station.
>
> **ADMIRAL**: If I didn't know you better, commander, I'd think you were just making excuses [...]
>
> **ADMIRAL**: Don't bother me with details. Just clean up the mess, Commander. And quickly. Before this becomes a permanent stain on your record. Do I make myself clear?
>
> **SISKO**: Yes, sir.

But in the episode I notice only 3 seconds in which I weakly hear Sisko say something like:

> I am fully aware of the situation, we are facing...

and immediately after, leaving this up in the air, I hear Bashir saying,

> What do you think they're telling him?

Why was this cut in the video? Is it a mistake?

Comment: Okay,. I've did a deep space searching, and I've found that it was a not acted script, just a trace to make the actors aware of the context

Comment: @Valorum   "Are you asking why a fan-written transcript is incomplete?"    No, Bento was saying the fan-written transcript was more complete than the actual episode which Bento watched  - an episode that might have been edited shorter than the original episode.

Comment: [According to Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/440.htm), there are two dialogues running in parallel: Sisko and the admiral talking in the background, and the rest of the crew in the foreground gossiping about it. (This scene is almost at the end of the transcript, under the last [Ops] header.) If another transcript included the background dialogue but not the program note describing it, that might be your confusion.

Comment: @M.A.Golding in fact the episode, basing on my web research, **is** shorter. That lacking part was in the transcript only for making actors aware of the situation. This is the explication I've found. The movie consists only of a few seconds in which Sisko mutters something, then the scene passes immediately to the crew outside the commander's office (Kira, Odo, etc)

Comment: @Cadence I had exactly read that transcript, but when it incidentally said **Sisko is having the following inaudible but heated argument with someone on his desk monitor behind the main dialogue. Everyone is watching.** it sounded very strange to me, if not incomprehensible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [Deep Space Nine Companion](https://books.google.nl/books?id=kDe3VS07YSMC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=%22I%20don%27t%20have%20to%20remind%20the%20admiral%20how%20many%20people%20pass%22&source=bl&ots=hSiwtEl6ET&sig=ACfU3U3UBYW9qy-xT3ItCoFxwOX_EYVEvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT7fj6q5ztAhVtMOwKHX-EBfAQ6AEwAnoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22I%20don%27t%20have%20to%20remind%20the%20admiral%20how%20many%20people%20pass%22&f=false). In short, the scene was written to explain to Avery Brooks (Sisko) what he's supposed to be portraying, emotionally speaking. It was never intended to be heard by the audience, except in brief.

> The top of Act 5 features Kira, Odo, O’Brien,
> Dax, and Bashir standing around in Ops, comment-
> ing on a conversation taking place between Sisko and
> a Starfleet representative via com in his office. They
> can’t hear what he’s saying, but the heated tone of the
> conversation is obvious. In fact, a scene was filmed
> and later cut, in which Sisko follows up on the close
> of the conversation by picking up his desk monitor
> and throwing it to the floor.
>
> Wonder what got him so steamed? The addendum to Scene 47 is a scene that was never intended to be heard by the audience but was written to give
> Avery Brooks something to play against.
>
> This is the dialogue Sisko is having with an
> admiral on the monitor in his office. We neither hear
> the dialogue nor see the Admiral on the monitor.

You can see the full scene in the [original script](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/440.txt) (listed as an addendum).

> **This is an ADDENDUM to Scene 47.**
>
> It should be placed after the Pronunciation Guide in the script.
>
> This is the dialogue Sisko is having with an Admiral on the monitor
> in his office.  **We neither hear the dialogue nor see the Admiral on
> the monitor.**
>
> We do see Sisko trying to keep his temper while emphatically
> responding to the Admiral's heated inquiries.
>
> They are mid-conversation as the scene begins...

Comment: 47 strikes again.

Comment: I've never seen something like that. Curiously I've gone to the transcript in that point for other reasons, and unexpectedly I've found the Easter egg